# Mini cart is not working after adding custom theme

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom, mini-cart

Mini-cart  Stopped working after adding custom theme in magento 2.1.6.
Any one please help me.

**[Note: I have already upload vendor template,layout and web file in our theme ]**

[image]

Please see image above:

Comment: Please confirm whether u have set not visibility for the product from admin end ? http://prntscr.com/fup6tj

Comment: No,I have set catalog search for product

Comment: This related to your theme for sure! Don't know you changes or modify before, Could you please provide some code of minicart.phtml in your theme or any layout code related? Btw You should check problem with knockout in console first

Comment: Did You have any knowledge related to this consoles error?..I am very new in magneto2 and I want to all module files are working with my custom theme.